# Can you specify a named-range based on a rule in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, rules, microsoft-excel-365, named-ranges

For instance, I have a dataset that has many named ranges in it, but I find that the range gets out of sync when I add rows below it.

If a column a row (for instance, id) starts with a specific number or some other fuzzy identifier in the range that I'm interested in keeping in the named range, can it be added to the range based on the rule that for instance it starts with 311XXXXX ?

Comment: Simplest method of having a dynamic range is to use a **Table** and structured references.  There are other methods, but you'd need to supply more detailed information.

Comment: I'll admit I am struggling to understand what you might mean by "If a column a row of a row"

Comment: It's falling out of sync because you're "adding rows below it".  Instead, you should always copy and **insert row *as*** or ***prior to*** the **bottom-most row** (as in `context menu`/`right click`, `e`; if you didn't select the entire row, you'll get a prompt on which direction to push the displaced cells).